# How do I count duplicates in an array with Ramda?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have an array with duplicate values and I need to find out how many times each value occurs in the array using ramda.js.

This is my array:
*[2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017]*

This is what I want to get out of it:
*[3, 4, 7, 5, 3]*

Here's an example of how it might work in pure JavaScript.

```
function count (arr) {
  const counts = {}
  arr.forEach((x) => { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1 })
  return Object.values(counts)
}
```

Comment: const ary = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4]; R.countBy(r=> r)(ary)

Comment: That seems a surprising requirement.  A result like `{2013: 3, 2014: 4, 2015: 7, 2016: 5, 2017: 3}` seems much more useful, and it's even easier to get, using just `R.countBy`.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that (like in your code) the duplicates don't have to be in sequence, you can get the same results with `R.countBy()` and `R.values()`:

```js
const { pipe, countBy, identity, values } = R;

const arr = [2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017]

const countDupes = pipe(
  countBy(identity),
  values
)

console.log(countDupes(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```